Name the movie in which boy dies at the end?
I saw a movie on HBO last year.. i only saw last few minutes of the movie in which a boy dies in the end, and on his funeral this poem is singed in the church.     I can fly but i want his wings i can shine in the darkness but i crave the light that he brings, My Angel Gabriel. Please help me finding the name of that movie.

HBO's Mary and Martha with Hilary Swank from 2013. You can see the song in the boy's funeral here:




Thank you very much... what a fast response... thank you thankyou

i minute to check
